# Existe algum risco ao desconectar o dispositivo android durante a depuração?

Tags: android

Não sei porque mas fiquei com um pouco de receio ao pensar que uma vez que meu ADT está em contato constante com meu Dispositivo(Nexus 5) ao desconectar durante uma troca de informações pode haver danos. Será que assim como um pendrive ao desconectar abruptamente durante a passagem ou troca de informações há riscos? Alguém já fritou parte de um dispostivo assim? Obrigado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR** - Nada que você deva se preocupar.

**Resposta longa**:

Os riscos envolvidos em uma desconexão da porta USB durante a depuração são exatamente os mesmos ao que o dispositivo está sujeito durante uso quotidiano.

Em algumas implementações USB antigas era possível remover um dispositivo enquanto o host ainda esta fornecendo energia para o dispositivo. Hoje isso é bem raro.

O problema principal com a remoção sem ejeção é o fato que alguns sistemas operacionais fazem cache em memória de arquivos sendo manipulados em mídia removível. Como na prática você não está manipulando arquivos (ADB se encarrega de 'serializar' e enviar seus APKs utilizando seu próprio protocolo), este risco é inexistente.

Do lado do dispositivo, o ambiente operacional se assegura que seu novo pacote APK só será instalado caso a transferência ocorra com sucesso.

Comment: Muito bom, retirou minha duvida, sem sombra para questionamentos. Obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Eu já tive a experiência de desconectar um dispositivo Android enquanto fazia uma transferência de arquivos e a fonte do PC **queimou** na hora. Isso aconteceu comigo apenas uma vez, hoje faço isso meio que seguido e nunca tive esse problema novamente. Porém, foi o simples ato de eu desconectar o USB e a fonte queimou.

Comment: Eu lembro de um caso onde um desenvolvedor fez o mesmo - retirou um dispositivo da porta USB - e a vítima foi a placa mãe. Isso aconteceu por que não a porta USB não tinha nenhum tipo de segurança contra curto-circuito (que ele provocou ao tirar o dispositivo inclinando lateralmente).